# Uses of Index in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to Index Constraints in SQL Server... Can anybody instruct me to clear my doubt... I've created an Index named EmpName by using the EName as ColumnName.

> Create index EmpName on Users_Info (EName)

How can I check the use of created Index in the SQL????

And I wanna know the difference of search results in the presence & absence of Index...

Thanks

Comment: Check out documentation to give you good information to start. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that can be important when we speak about indexes and performance:

1.There are dozen (about 10) of index types. The Most commonly usage have clustered and no-clustered indexes. Clustered indexes are indexes that ordering rows in some table and no-clustered indexes make additional tables that refers to main table.
2.Because of that no-clustered indexes improve performance during execution of select statement but keep in mind that no-clustered indexes slows down update, insert and delete operations.

Comment: Fine Thanks alot... In Non-clustered indexes, how can i check the search results of the table after creating index... which means how can i check the performance of select statement in the database?

Comment: As you can see in other comments, execution plans give us cost execution of some query, you can visit some of the links and explore that more deeply, it is not so simple to explain in one comment. If you want to check performance on some test data, you need before every execution of some query to clear query cache with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and clear execution plan cache with DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. In your case, you need to execute functions that i give you and then execute your query without index and after that create index, execute DBCC functions again and execute your query.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQL Execution Plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - These will help you when analysing the performance of your tables and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQL DMV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) (Dynamic Management Views) as they provide helpful performance information. [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) provides usage on indexes organized by database, object (id of the table) and index_id (id of the index).